# Color underline a formula

Tags: math-mode, color

I want to underline different parts of a formula with different colors. What is the best possible option? Soul seems only to provide one color per document.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox\MBox
\newcommand\Cline[2][red]{{\sbox\MBox{$#2$}%
  \rlap{\usebox\MBox}\color{#1}\rule[-1.2\dp\MBox]{\wd\MBox}{0.5pt}}}
\begin{document}

\[ f(x)=\int_1^\infty\Cline{x^2+\frac12\ln(x)}\mathrm{d}x
       = \Cline[blue]{\int_1^\infty x^2} \mathrm{d}x 
       + \Cline[cyan]{\int_1^\infty\frac12\ln(x)} \mathrm{d}x \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

This is a slightly different method than that provided by Herbert and Alan, using TeX's own little known command `\underline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\mathunderline#1#2{\color{#1}\underline{{\color{black}#2}}\color{black}}
\begin{document}

\[ f(x)=\int_1^\infty\mathunderline{red}{x^2+\frac12\ln(x)}\mathrm{d}x
       = \mathunderline{blue}{\int_1^\infty x^2} \mathrm{d}x 
       + \mathunderline{green}{\int_1^\infty\frac12\ln(x)} \mathrm{d}x \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work much better for nested underlining than Herbert’s box solution (haven’t tried alan’s `soul` solution).

Answer (score 10):

You can easily create a multicoloured version of the `\ul` command using the `soul` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

%This command takes a colour as an optional argument; the default colour is black.

\newcommand{\myul}[2][black]{\setulcolor{#1}\ul{#2}\setulcolor{black}}

\begin{document}
     \myul[red]{Red underline}

     \myul[blue]{blue underline}

     \myul[green]{green underline}

     \myul{black underline}
 \end{document}
```

It appears this solution doesn't work for underlining in math mode, so Herbert's solution is clearly best.  For regular text, this solution will work as advertised.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in `beamer`.

Comment: To use with `beamer`, check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41683/

Answer (score 3):

In ConTeXt, one can use `\mframed` for underlining text. `\mframed` is a version of `\framed` that takes care of math scaling. `\mframed` takes all the options of `\framed`, so getting an underline is as simple as setting `frame=off` and `bottomframe=on`. You can choose the color of a frame by setting `framecolor=<name of color>`. Combining all this, here is a macro that changes the color of the underline:

```
\def\highlight
  {\dosingleargument\dohighlight}

\def\dohighlight[#1]%
  {\mframed[frame=off,bottomframe=on,framecolor=red,frameoffset=3pt,#1]}
```

This can be used as follows

```
\setupcolors[state=start]

\starttext
Consider 
  $f(x) = \highlight{\int_1^{\infty} x^2 + \frac {1}{2} \ln(x) dx}$. This can be
  simplified as
\startformula
  f(x) = \highlight{\int_1^{\infty} x^2 + \frac {1}{2} \ln(x) dx}
       = \highlight[framecolor=blue] { \int_1^{\infty} x^2} dx 
       + \highlight[framecolor=blue] { \int_1^{\infty} \frac {1}{2} \ln(x)} dx
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

which gives the following result.
[image]

Notice that the `\int` is scaled correctly, both for inline math as well as for display math.

Answer (score 2):

I had difficulty using any of the above methods in `beamer`, but found that simply changing the color, declaring the underline, and then changing the color back inside the underline command seemed to work.  For example:

```
\newcommand{\rul}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\underline{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}}
```

gives me the new command `\rul{sample text}` which underlines the black sample text in red.  I suspect the above methods are more sophisticated, but this seems to work fine for me, and does not require the `soul` package.