# How do I capture the existing color of a group?

Tags: color, programming

My question is a follow-up of my answer to this question  [Color underline a formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/color-underline-a-formula)

My answer would have been much better, if I could save the color of the text and then restore it.  Is it possible to capture the active color of a group and if yes, how does one do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save the current color by

```
\colorlet{currentcolor}{.}
```

`.` is just a placeholder for the currently active color. You may choose a name for the color, I just chose `currentcolor`. Later just use

```
\color{currentcolor}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we don't have to save the color.

You can try `\color@begingroup` and `\color@endgroup`, which is used in LaTeX core heavily.
In fact, there is no difference between `\begingroup` and `\color@begingroup`, and `\color@endgroup` is defined as `\endgraf\endgroup`.

After all, @Stefan's solution is still better in many situations.