# Why is it that coloring in soul in beamer is not visible

Tags: beamer, color, highlighting, soul

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{soul,color} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
\hl{Hello World} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

I  process this with `pdflatex` and I do not see the expected highlight.
If I try to assign a color to overstrike same thing happens, as in

```
\setstcolor{red}
\st{Hello}
```

but `\st{hello}` by itself does overstrike `hello` in black when no color is set.
Why is that and what is a work-around? Many That I tried do not work with long text.

The [Soul Package Documentation](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/plain/contrib/soul/soul.pdf), footnote 5, says something about needing a Postscript driver.

I do not have a problem using `soul` package outside of `beamer`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`beamer` redefines nearly everything ... So we have to redefine `\set@color` and
`reset@color` to its original definition before using `\hl`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\let\HL\hl
\renewcommand\hl{%
  \let\set@color\beamerorig@set@color
  \let\reset@color\beamerorig@reset@color
  \HL}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}   
Hello World
    
\hl{Hello World} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works also e.g. for `\ul{...}`. Could you add a bit of explanation how? Thanks!

Comment: To make it work for `\ul`, you would of course need to add something like `\makeatletter \let\UL\ul \renewcommand\ul{\let\set@color\beamerorig@set@color \let\reset@color\beamerorig@reset@color \UL} \makeatother` (so just replace `\hl` by `\ul` and `\HL` by `\UL` in the above code).