# How to strikethrough text in red inside beamer using soul? (inside a tabular)

Tags: beamer, strikeout

I was trying to strike through text inside a `beamer` frame, using package `soul` and changing color to red. It is inside a `tabular`, but I've tried outside and couldn't make it work either. I also tried moving the `\setstcolor{red}` command around, with no success.

I was using the package `soul`, but any other solutions is fine, as long as it works.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{soul}               % to striketrhourhg text

\begin{document}
\setstcolor{red}
\begin{frame}[c,fragile]

\begin{tabular}{ c c }
     three & four \\
    \st{one} \& \st {two} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Answer (score 6):

With `ulem` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}               % to striketrhourhg text
\newcommand\redout{\bgroup\markoverwith
{\textcolor{red}{\rule[0.5ex]{2pt}{0.8pt}}}\ULon}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
     three & four \\
    \redout{one} \& \redout {two} & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution if you want to keep using the `soul` package; the new command `\St` is overlay aware:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{soul}               % to striketrhourhg text

\makeatletter
\newcommand\SoulColor{%
  \let\set@color\beamerorig@set@color
  \let\reset@color\beamerorig@reset@color}
\makeatother
\newcommand<>{\St}[1]{\only#2{\SoulColor\st{#1}}}

\setstcolor{red}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c,fragile]
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
     three & four \\
    \St{one} & \St{two} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

the patch used was the one in [`Herbert's answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41693/3954) to [Why is it that coloring in soul in beamer is not visible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41683/3954).