# Underline in red

Tags: color, underline

The `\underline` command only adds black underline. `\usepackage` command, however, is not allowed in StackOverflow questions so there is no way to use `\color{red}\uline{...}`. Is there any chance to apply underline in red like below to text of questions in StackOverflow? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The question and solution of [Underline Text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321217/underline-text-change-underline-colors-in-consecutive-sentences) should be helpful.

Comment: I have explicitly restricted the scope in StackOverflow settings in the original question, which occupies nearly half of the question, not general Latex.

Comment: Questions about MathJax and friends (as used by StackOverflow) are generally off-topic here since they only accept a LaTeX-like input, but are not actually based on TeX or LaTeX. You might have a better chance asking this on StackOverflow (which has a MathJax tag).